# How to get notification from Scintilla on caret movent

Tags: scintilla

I see Scintilla firing events on text change and other actions but it seems that it does not fire an event on caret movement. Is there a way to get this info from Scintilla?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you mean **caret** movements (the cursor only relates to mouse movements). More generally, you want to be notified of *selection* changes, since they must always imply caret changes (and vice-versa). In addition, you will need to consider *content* changes, since they could also indirectly affect the caret position and/or selection (e.g. cut, paste, delete, etc).

Scintilla provides information about all such changes via the [SCN_UPDATEUI](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCN_UPDATEUI) notification.

Comment: Yes, **caret** movements. And **SCN_UPDATEUI** is it. Thanks!